# Tokenization and AST

Tags: c++, c, static-analysis, abstract-syntax-tree

Have a rather abstract question for you all. I'm looking at getting involved in a static code analysis project. It uses C and C++ as the language to develop in so if any code could be in either of those languages in your response that would be great.

My question:
I need to understand some of the basic concepts/constructs used to process code for static analysis. I have heard people use things like AST and tokenization etc. I was just wondering if anything can clarify how these things are applied in creating a static analysis tool? Id like more of an explanation of tokenization as I dont really understand that so well. I understand it is a sort of way to process strings but I'm not confident in that answer. Furthermore, I know that the project I'm looking at passes the code through the preprocessor before it is analyzed. Can anyone explain this? Surely if it is static code analysis it needn't be preprocessed?

Hope someone can clear this up for me.

Cheers.

Comment: Regarding the pre-processor. If you are analyzing C or C++ code, it contains a lot or pre-processing directives (like `#define` and `#include`). Instead of handling those directives yourself it's easier to let the pre-processor handle it and leaving a pure C or C++ file for you.

Comment: Ah cheers, that makes total sense. Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: Is this static analysis focused on analyzed C or C++, or is the static analyzer *implemented* in those languages, and it processes something else?

Comment: Its both written in C/C++ and analyzes it.

Comment: OK.  What is it using to parse C and C++?

Comment: Honestly, this is where my knowledge fails me. I'm not even sure where to start looking for that information. This is where I could use some help. Can you point me to where I might look? I'm looking at the tool CPPcheck.

Comment: According (GIYF) to http://gamedevelopersrefuge.org/viewtopic.php?t=1059&sid=0e0e7e623aad72da95fd9ddae3421f94, "what this (cppcheck) does is preprocess and tokenize the input then scans for method definitions then does a whole bunch of hand coded crap". Assuming this is correct, it sounds like an ad hoc parser, and you can't build a *good* static analysis tool if your tool doesn't really understand the language.  I'd look elsewhere.   I get the impression you haven't had a compiler class.  If not, better start there or you'll just spin your wheels.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Upon writing a build-system (mostly for learning purposes), I realised that at least with GNU cpp, the output is not pure C++, neither is it pure C, as it contains some GCC specifica. However, that's nothing really chill-full if you are into parsing anyways.

Comment: @phresnel You're sure that it's no macros that expands to non-standard code? Could you perhaps give an example?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: `echo "#include <something>" > test.cpp && cpp test.cpp"`, and you'll see a lot of position markers like `# 785 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4`. Not a hard thing to parse, but non-standard.

Comment: @phresnel Ah the non-standard line control... You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tokenization is the act of breaking source text into language elements such as operators, variable names, numbers, etc.  Parsing reads sequences of tokens and build [Abstract Syntax Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), which is a particular program representation. Tokenization and parsing are necessary for static analysis, but hardly interesting, in the same way that ante-to-the-pot is necessary to playing poker but not the interesting part of the game in any way.

If you are building a static analyzer (you imply you expect to work on one implemented in C or C++), you will need fundamental knowledge of compiling (parsing  not so much unless you are building a parser for the language to be statically analyzed), but certainly about program representations (ASTs, triples, control and data flow graphs, ...), type and property inference, and limits on analysis accuracy (the cause of conservative analyses.
The program representations are fundamental because these are the data structures that most static analysers really process; its simply too hard to wring useful facts directly from program text.  These concepts can be used to implement static analysis capabilities in any programming language to implement analysis type tools; there's nothing special in implementing them in C or C++.

Run, don't walk, to your nearest compiler class for the first part of this.  If you don't have it, you won't be able to do anything effective in tool building.  The second part you will more likely find in a graduate computer science class.

If you get past that basic knowledge issue, you will either decide to implement an analysis tool from scratch, or build on existing analysis tool infrastructure.  Few people decide to build one from scratch; it takes a huge amount of work (years or decades) to build robust parsers, flow analyzers, etc. needed as foundations for any particular static analysis.  Mostly people try to use some existing infrastructure.

There's a huge list of candidates at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis

If you insist on processing C or C++ and building your own custom sophisticated analysis, you *really*, *really* need a tool that can handle real C and C++ code.  There are IMHO a limited number of good candidates:

- GCC (and various graft ons such as Starynkevitch's MELT, about which I know little)
- Clang (pretty spectacular toolset)
- [DMS](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) (and its [C and C++ front ends](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds))  [my company's tool]
- Open64 compiler infrastructure
- Rose compiler infrastructure (based on EDG's industry-wide front end)

Each one of these are big systems and require a big investment to understand and begin to use.  Don't underrate the learning curve.

There are lots of other tools out there that sort of process C and C++, but "sort of" is pretty useless for static analysis purposes.

If you intend to simply *use* a static analysis tool, you can avoid learning most of the parsing and program representation questions; instead you'll need to learn as much as you can about the specific analysis tool you intend to use.    You'll still be a lot better off with the compiler background above because you will understand what the tool does, why it does it, and why it produces the kinds of answers that it does (usually it produces answers that are unsatisfying in a lot of ways due to the conservative limits on analysis accuracy).

Lastly, you should be clear that you understand the difference between *static analysis* and *dynamic analysis* [using data collected at runtime to determine program properties].  Most end users couldn't care less how you get information about their code, and each analysis approach has its strength and weaknesses.

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in static analysis, you should not bother about syntax analysis (i.e. lexing, parsing, building the abstract syntax tree), because that won't learn you much.

So I suggest you to use some existing parsing infrastructure. This is particularly true if you want to analyze C++ source code, because just coding a C++ parser is a difficult thing to do.

For example, you could leverage on the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, or on the [LLVM/Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler. Be aware of their open source license: GCC is under GPLv3, and Clang/LLVM has a BSD-like license. GCC is able to handle not only C & C++, but also Fortran, Go, Ada, Objective-C.

Because of the GPLv3 license of GCC, your development above it should be also free software under GPLv3. However, that also means that the GCC community is quite big. If you know Ocaml and are interested of static analysis of C only, you could consider [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/) (LGPL licensed)

Actually, I am working on GCC, by providing the [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension framework (MELT is also GPLv3 licensed). MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC and should be the ideal choice to work on static analysis using the powerful framework and internal representations (Gimple, Tree, ...) of GCC.

(Of course, LLVM folks would be delighted to have their work used too; and nobody knows well both LLVM and GCC, because learning such big software is already a challenge, so people have to choose on which they invest their time).

So my suggestion is to **join an existing static analysis or compiler effort**, don't reinvent the wheel by starting from scratch (because that means years of effort, just to have a good parser).

By so doing, you will take advantage of the existing infrastructure (so you won't bother about AST-s and parsing) and you will improve some existing project.

I would be very delighted if you are interested in MELT. FWIW, there is a MELT tutorial at Paris, on january 24<sup>th</sup> 2012, [HiPEAC conference](http://www.hipeac.net/conference/paris/cfp).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'd really like to make that conference actually (I'm at uni in Scotland so not too far away) but alas university work limits my movements at the moment. Would the conference content be online? I'm very interested in getting into this kind of project. It ties in nicely with my interests with the Linux kernel exploitation.

Comment: Ok, do you have a link to the conference schedule so I might view them when they go up?

Comment: "not bother about learning syntax analysis"  Well, you don't need to know a lot, but you have to understand the basic idea *and the limitations* or how these tools work won't make any sense at all.  After all, if you haven't fought with syntax analysis, all the issues that the preprocessor brings may be simply unobvious.

Comment: Well, if you use a tool which already does the syntax analysis, you should bother to understand its internal representations (abstract syntax tree etc...)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking into static analysis for C & C++, your first stop should be [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html), along with its associated papers.

In terms of why the preprocessor is run, static analysis is meant to catch errors and possible unintended code functionality (very basically), this it must analyse what the compiler will be compiling, not what the user sees.

I'm pretty sure @Ira Baxter will popup with a far more complete answer :)

Comment: Cheers for the response. I suppose you need to consider the code from a processors perspective rather than, as you say, as the user would see it. Technically tho are you not then analyzing a partially compiled piece of code??

Comment: You are often analyzing the AST inside e.g. the GCC compiler (or as provided by the Clang/LLVM infrastructure), which happens after pre-processing & parsing. So indeed you are not analyzing text, but some internal, more digested, more structured, form.

Comment: @Necrols: dang it, you've forced my hand... I might have gotten away with a 3 line answer otherwise :-{

Comment: @IraBaxter: glad to be of help :P